# SetInterval long running script error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a application where I will get data from a service and I need to display paged data. Each page contains 16 records. Based on that the no of pages will be dynamically displayed. I use jquery fadeout/fadein to display each page fading after 8 seconds. After the last page is displayed, I am calling the service again and updating the data. All the while, I am using SetInterval to loop through each pages. Below is the code snippet of the page display

```
if (deppages > 1) {
    $dels.slice(1).hide();
    clearInterval(depinterval);
    depinterval = setInterval(function () {
        $("#pmain .sptotpg").promise().done(function () {
            if (a == deppages - 1) {
                getData();
            }
        });

        $dels.eq(a).fadeOut(500, function () {

            if (a == deppages - 1)
                a = deppages;
            else
                a = (a + 1) % deppages;

            if (a > 0) {
                //$("#legend").show("fast");
                //$("#footermsg").css("bottom", "-76px");
                //$("#pmain").css("height", "");
            }
            else {

                if ($("#airlines").css("display") == "none")
                    $("#footermsg").css("bottom", "-46px");

            }

            $dels.eq(a).fadeIn(500, function () {                    
            });


        })
    }, 23000);
}
```

The issue I am facing is, after the application is running for few hours, I am getting long running script error. Can anyone suggest me any where I went wrong?

**EDIT**

I have implemented similar functionality in another way but getting same error for that one as well. In production environment, the page is kept open all day and is never closed. Basically I am building all the pages at once and looping (fadein/out) them and in the last page, I am trying to get the data from service again and build the pages

```
function fadeContent() {
   $("#flightsinfo .pg:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(23000).queue(function (next) {
        if ($(this).attr("a") == $(last).attr("a")) {
            $('.flpg').html("");
            getData();
        }

        next();
    }).fadeOut(500, function () {

            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());

            fadeContent();

            if (noofpages > 1 && flagcnt <= noofpages) {
                if ($(this).parent().find('.wrapper').length > 0 && noofpages > 1) {
                    $('.flpg').html("Now showing page " + (flagcnt) + " of " + noofpages);
                    flagcnt++;
                }
                else {
                    $('.flpg').html("");
                    flagcnt = 2;
                }
            }
            else {
                $('.flpg').html("");                    
            }

    });
}
```

This is how I get the data

```
function getData() {
loadSettings();

$("#flightsinfo").html("");
$('.flpg').html("");

var refurl = new Date().getTime();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: serviceurl,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {

        buildContent(data, false);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("cacheddata") != null) {
            var restoredata = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sessionStorage.getItem("cacheddata"), "text/xml");
            buildContent(restoredata, true);
        }
        else {
            $("#screen").empty();
            $("#screen").append(def);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: can you show the script error?

Comment: Are you adding elements every 8 seconds? If you are then at some point there may be too many elements and jQuery selectors take too long to complete. If you're not planning to show older pages then you should remove them from the dom `$dels.slice(1).hide();$dels.slice(2).remove()`

Comment: Will try to do removing the page from dom and check, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that did not worked as I am building all the paged content at once